# Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined - template is named

Tags: javascript, meteor

In main.js Template.main is undefined but I don't understand why. Both files are in the /client dir.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

**main.html**

```
<head>
    <title>QuizAero</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">QuizAero Admin Dashboard</a>
        </div>
    </header>
      <template name="main">
      {{#each categories}}
      <div id="mainSection" class="col-lg-3 pull-left">
        {{categories}}
      </div>
      {{/each}}
      </template>
</div>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  var categoryNames = [
    {
      title: 'Air Law'
    },
    {
      title: 'Meteorology'
    },
    {
      title: 'Navigation'
    }];

  Template.main.helpers({
    categories: categoryNames
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

First you need to declare you template tag outside the body.

Second, you need to properly insert the template with: `{{>main}}`

Third, inside the `each`, the data context changed to item being iterated and you can access the property `title`

HTML: https://gist.github.com/mariorodriguespt/5215a98538b89b8af9ab

Comment: Thanks! Very concise answer.